# Facebook login Android registration

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm trying to add at my app the Facebook login in the home page, but I don't understand how to work Facebook API. I read the development tools of Facebook, but I don't understand how to work the method.

I need to incorporate the Facebook data in my already exist Mysql db. 
First of all I'm trying to login in this way :

```
    package com.example.anto.loginapp;

   import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.Login;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText edUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edUser);
        final EditText edPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edPass);
        final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etRegister);


        final TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);

        //registrazione normale

        registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });


        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


        LoginButton login_button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        //ask permission to Facebook
        login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email", "user_birthday"));


        //LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
        // Callback registration
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Intent fbIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(fbIntent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I m trying to readdress (after the Facebook login) to my user area. All working well, I see the button, working (because if I press open the facebook login), on Facebook I see my app authorization, but when I press continue, the app return to Login area. If I press again, the facebook login say me "u previous loggin...continue" but if I continue return again to login. 
I'm make crazy, probably is simple to understand, but I can't see where.

After this I can use the Facebook data to import in my db (mysql). I what way? because I try to create a Json array, but in the log i dont see nothing (i m using a command Log.d, and use Logcat to see something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your onSuccess method is not called.

Please add the below code to your login activity.

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Make your CallbackManager as global variable.